# How to narrow down where the change was as part of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component class A which contains as state a data object containing an array of objects, each of these objects have an attribute, and I need to know with the `useEffect` which index actually changed:

**Component A**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default class ComponentA extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        data: Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(i => {
          return { 
            id: i,
            data: props.initialData
          };   
        });
      };
   }

   // at this point I have my state and want to monitor changes 
   // but how to monitor useEffect and tell which index element 
   // within state.data changed?
   
   
};
```

Comment: You cannot utilize a `useEffect` hook inside of a class based component. You need to convert to a functional component

Comment: @JBrown ok thanks, but can you make the equivalent solution of useEffect to the class Component using a class component hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to convert your component to a functional component to use a `useEffect` hook. I would do something like this:

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({initialData}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(i => {
    return {
      id: i,
      data: initialData
    };
  });
  
  return // some jsx
)};
```

As far as your question, I would update some state variable that tracks the id of the object being changed when you update `state`. For example, when you call `setState` and change one of the objects in the array, also set some other piece of state called `changedId` with the id of the object you changed. Once the `useEffect` is called, the state has already been changed and it is too late to check what the change was.

Here is how I would do that generally:

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({initialData}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(i => {
    return {
      id: i,
      data: initialData
    };
  });)
  const [changedId, setChangedId] = useState(null);
  
  // Somewhere else in the app you change the state...
  // Update the changedId at that time
  const someStateUpdatingFunction = () => {
    setState(//newValue)
    setChangedId(//idForChangedArrayItem)
  }
  
  // Then once the state updates, the effect is called
  useEffect(() => {
     //some effect here
  }, [state])
  
  return // some jsx
};
```

Hope that is helpful. Just remember, the `useEffect` hook does not track state changes over time. It is simply some functionality that is triggered **when** the state changes.